# Woocommerce disabling payment gateway based on shipping method

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I've got a problem with disabling a Paypal payment method - it had worked before on other sites, sadly for some reason wont work on this one.

Code im using:

```
function my_custom_available_payment_gateways( $gateways ) {
$chosen_shipping_rates = ( isset( WC()->session ) ) ? WC()->session->get( 'chosen_shipping_methods' ) : array();

    if ( in_array( 'flexible_shipping_6_1', $chosen_shipping_rates ) ) :
    unset( $gateways['cod'] );

    elseif ( in_array( 'flexible_shipping_7_2', $chosen_shipping_rates ) ) :
    unset( $gateways['bacs'] );
    unset( $gateways['paypal'] );

endif;
return $gateways; 
} 
add_filter( 'woocommerce_available_payment_gateways', 'my_custom_available_payment_gateways' );
```

It unsets bacs for flex shipping 7_2 but wont disable paypal even tho the value is correct

```
<input id="payment_method_paypal" type="radio" class="input-radio" name="payment_method" value="paypal" data-order_button_text="Kontynuuj do PayPal">
<input id="payment_method_bacs" type="radio" class="input-radio" name="payment_method" value="bacs" data-order_button_text="">
```